# Who was "The guy" Mike was talking about?

Tags: breaking-bad

In Season 4, episode 5, Mike and Jesse are out checking drop points. At one point in the episode Jesse mentions he could be "The guy", Mike then pulls over and rants to him about how this isn't in the cards: "You are not the guy, you're not capable of being the guy. **I had a guy but now I don't**. You are not the guy!"

In the bolded section, is it made clear who "The guy" is that he's referring to? I've thought it might have been Victor, he and Mike often worked together quite a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I can't really do much else to prove this either and can only agree with you there. In the way he said that I'm pretty sure he does indeed mean *Victor*, especially seeing that there couldn't really be anyone else he'd be talking about that we know of, and for a simple throwaway line without any meaning it was just too prominent.

Afterall *Mike* was at first not very happy to play babysitter for *Jesse* in whatever strange play *Gus* had set up. Add to this that he was also very upset about *Victor*'s death and especially the fact that this was pretty much the fault of the two "intruders" *Jesse* and *Walt*. And now he has to care for someone who'll probably never be able to hold up to the guy whose death he was responsible for (and the fact that he didn't have a high opinion about *Jesse*'s attitude and false confidence either, at least at first). So yeah, he's definitely talking about *Victor* there.